# How to use Threading in QDialog to fill data in QComboBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have 10 QComboBox in QDialog. And i am filling data into these combobox while opening Dialog, It will take 7 second to load Dialog, how to solved this issue because there is no clicked slot in combobox . I think we can solved this issue by using Thread but i have no idea of QThread.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not easy because QT does not allow for widgets to be modified outside main thread.

**Simple solution:**
Use threads to put the data into QStringLists and set it using addItems.
QThreadPool is more simple to use for this usecase.
This solution will not help if the problem is the size of the data itself, not the processing.

**Complex solution (nice for learning):**
You can however re-implement the model of the widget (QAbstractItemModel), and use a QThread in the model.

Also you can create your own QListView derivered class that on loads data when setVisible is called for the first time with true - just overwrite setVisible(bool).
Set an instance of this class to each combo box with setView().

On how to use QThread, see examples, read tutorials... It is to complex to explain here, but there is full of examples and tutorials on the net.

Later Edit:

There is also possible to use event filters:

```
// Install event filter
MyDlg::MyDlg()
{
     qApp->installEventFilter ( this );
}

// search for the view of the combo to be activated
// and fill it.
bool MyDlg::eventFilter ( QObject * obj, QEvent * event )
{
    QSet<QAbstractItemView *> myComboViews;

    my_combos.insert(combo1->view());

    if ( event->type () == QEvent::Show )
    {
        QAbstractItemView * view = qobject_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(obj);
        if ( myComboViews.contains(obj) && view->isVisible() )
        {
            fillComboView(view);
        }
    }
    return QDialog::eventFilter ( obj, event );
}
```

The code is untested, but you can get the ideea.

Comment: Thanks Dragos, i am trying to do with threading as you told. are there is any event such like combobox clicked ,if yes give me detail about that.

Comment: I could not find any signals emitted for this, but you could you can use event filters. I suggest to use the show event on the view of the combo, because the mouse click is harder to filter - you do not have access to the dropdown button.